# Sent JSON object with image

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I have a basic question. It is possible to send two parameter form POST method in Angular and Java Spring. One parameter is  JSON object second is an image.

I have a simple example in Angular to explain what I want:

```
addHero(file: File,category: CategoryModel): Observable<any> {
const formdata: FormData = new FormData();

formdata.append('file', file);
return this.http.post<File>(this.cateogryUrl, {formdata,category} )
  .pipe(
   // catchError(this.handleError('addHero', file))
  );
```

}

Comment: You want to send the data from Angular to JAVA right as it seems?

Comment: Yes, I want. Two parameters, one image a one JSON object.

Comment: You can use base64 for this should I give you demo code?

Comment: Yes, that will be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Check my example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always convert it to BASE64. Then it's a simple string which you can simply pass it within the JSON (or a different one).

EDIT

This is what i do in my case any time a user upload a file. Isimply transform the file chosen to a BASE64 string. There are some really nice resources out there about this.

```
onFileChanged(event) {
 const file = event.target.files[0];
 if (file.type.split('/')[0] !== 'image') {
  this.validFile = false;
 }
 this.imageUploadModel.ImageType = file.type.split('/')[1];

 const myReader: FileReader = new FileReader();
 myReader.onloadend = (e) => {
   this.imageUploadModel.Base64String = myReader.result.toString();
};
  myReader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

This is my model

```
export class ImageUploadModel {
  Title: string;
  Description: string;
  ImageType: string;
  Base64String: string;
}
```

And i stringify it so i can send it on the body of the request:

```
 const body = JSON.stringify(this.imageUploadModel);
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your backend. If it takes image as a multipartfile, you can't send json data with it. But you can append other values which is desired to the form data. If it takes image as a base64 file, you can use json object to send data.

Comment: This is my backed. 
 `@PostMapping("/saveCategory")
 @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
 public void createCategory(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, @RequestParam ProductModel product) {`

And I track for the best solution. What you think about which is approach is better?

Comment: If I understand well. I cannot send JSON and Multipart File together?

Comment: Yes you can do in this way. But when you do that, you can't send ProductModel object as a json. Its fields need to be added to formdata. I am assuming that, ProductModel object has identifier, name, code and categoryId. Your formdata will be like that `
formdata.append('file', file);
formdata.append('identifier', identifier);
formdata.append('name', name);
formdata.append('code', code);
formdata.append('categoryId', categoryId);`

Comment: I have a very interesting thinks. I tried sent JSON and Image from POSTMAN and I hade error because is not possible to bind String in my ProductModel.  I have ideat to send separately my id, name to the server and after that bind in my ProductModel . What do you think about that?

Comment: It is your architecture. If you prefer this it is possible. But in this case you need to think about rollback scenario.

Comment: What do you think about set two calls, one for saving the image on the server and return the id of the image and another call for saving data with id in the DB?

Answer (score 1):

Hello there you need to follow these steps.

1. Convert File in to base 64 as

   `function getBase64(file) {
     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
      reader.onerror = error => reject(error);
     });
    }
    getBase64(file).then(base64=>{
      var base64 = base64;
    });`
2. Now you have to send the base64 with the formdata as

   `formdata.append('base64', base64); // base64 from the method`
3. Now get the base64 at JAVA and convert it in File at JAVA end.

Thank you :)
any query please comment down and thumbs up if you get your thing

Comment: May I get the green tick?

Answer (score 0):

```
formdata.append('file', file);
formdata.append('key1', value1);
formdata.append('key2', value2);
```

You can add multiple key pair value like this.

If there too many, you can also iterate in for loop

```
for(let key in someObject){
   formdata.append(key, someObject[key]);
}
```